# HazelCast | operation over IMap is distributed or not?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a class which performs operation over an IMap<...>.

```
public class CacheOperation
{
private IMap<Integer,String> cache;

 public CacheOperation(IMap<Integer,String> cache)
 { 
   this.cache=cache;
 }

 //api for get operation with/without lock over the key
 //api to delete data with lock
 //api to save data with lock over the key
 //...
}
```

I have various methods defined inside the class which perform operations over the IMap.
The IMap instance is populated when `CacheOperation` Bean is created.

```
@Bean
public CacheOperation cacheOperation(ClientConfig config )
{
    HazelcastInstance instcance=HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
    return new CacheOperation(instcance.getMap("mapName"))
}
```

My questions is, if i perform any operation over the IMap,  will it always be performed over the distributed Cache?
Or do i need to get the reference of IMap from HazelcastInstance for every operation.
Any thought on this would be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on using a single `IMap` instance (per map, unique by name), it will be consistent and always operating across the distributed cache.

Your `CacheOperation` bean and dependency injection configuration look fine to me.

For reference, the [IMap documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html) describes itself as *Concurrent, distributed, observable and queryable map* - and it really is as simple as that.